# Fix Background Color

Tags: html, css

How do you remove the colors in the corners?

```
body {
border: 30px solid #fff;
border-radius: 50px;
background-color: blue;
background-attachment: fixed;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
```

}

[image]

Comment: please create a working snippet so we can see the entire code for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html body have the following:

```
<body>
<div>
  <!-- all other body html here -->
</div>
</body>
```

Then in your css use:

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
body > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border: 30px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7bd5fjm/

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the border pixel size and it will cover up the corners

Answer (score 0):

You should add an extra div tag and add the background color there instead of in the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

TRY,

```
   body {
        border: 20px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        position: fixed;
        margin: -15px; //Pulling the border outwards.
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }
```

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: How about now? @BatuhanAkkaya

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it on the `body`, why not set it on a new element, like a `div` or something? But if you insist on keeping it on the body, setting white on the `html` is one way of doing it...

```
html {
    background: white;}
```

Comment: thank you. I can use the div if the problem is in the body.